# Может ли JVM сама расширять размер ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, jvm

Инициализация:

```
ArrayList<Integer> M1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(400);
M1.addAll(M2);
```

Comment: Не может, она это делает.

Comment: Нет, не может. Если вы имеете в виду -  может ли расширяться ArrayList при добавлении элементов, то да, ArrayList расширяется.

Comment: @aleshka-batman это не одно и то же?

Comment: @Suvitruf как JVM сама расширяет размер массива ? Это чушь какая-то. Только если явно самому его расширить.

Comment: массив != ArrayList.  В реализации метода add ArrayList'а предусмотрено увеличение емкости, но массив никак не увеличивается.

Comment: Столкнулся с тем, что при начально заданном объёме 400., в процессе добавления элементов размер оказался больше 1000.

Comment: @sapeg покажите код инициализации списка и его заполнения.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию, если используется пустой конструктор, создаётся список с [дефолтным значением capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--), которое будет равно `10`.

При добавлении 11 элемента, будет расширен список. В зависимости от JVM результирующий размер может быть разный. В Oracle jvm вроде на 50% растёт. Т.е, новый массив будет иметь размер 15.

Вы можете в конструктор передать размер начальный capacity. Тогда просто изначально внутри будет создан массив нужного размер (например, 400). Но при заполнении механизм расширения массива будет тем же самым, что и при дефолтном значении.

Если вопрос, конечно, про это.

Если вопрос в том, может ли jvm сама без изменений со стороны кода решить изменить размер списка, то нет, не может.

Comment: Значение было не дефолтным, а =400

Comment: @sapeg это после добавления скольких элементов?

Comment: больше 1000, ~по десятку за раз.

Comment: @sapeg изначальный размер был 10. При добавлении новых элементов и при превышении capacity размер менялся. Если вы предварительно знаете, сколько у вас будет элементов, то лучше инициализируйте с нужным capacity, что лишних копирований не было.

Comment: Добавил код в UPD.

Comment: @sapeg ну вот было 400. Вы добавили 1000 элемент, размер списка вырос. Не совсем понимаю, в чём вопрос то?

Comment: Ну т.е. видимо может JVM сама менять объём?

Comment: @sapeg она не меняет размер сама, она меняет размер в ответ на ваши действия.

Comment: Просто когда выходишь за границы обычного массива, JVM сразу выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @sapeg `ArrayList` - не обычный массив )

Comment: ...............ок

Comment: @sapeg, `ArrayList` хранит элементы в массиве (изначально размером `initial capacity`), но каждый раз, когда места в нём не достаточно для добавления новых элементов - выделяет новый массив большего размера, копирует туда содержимое старого и вставляет новые элементы. Именно для того чтобы не делать всё это вручную `ArrayList` и создан.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я это уже понял.

Comment: @sapeg это ответ помог вам, отметьте его решением.

Comment: Ответ нужно дополнить, т.к. я спрашивал про фиксированный размер, а там про дефолтный.

Comment: @sapeg в этом плане особой разницы нет.